# Different values for get_author_posts_url and get_the_author (posts 2 posts)

Tags: query, author, list-authors, plugin-posts-to-posts

*Caveat- I'm not a programmer, I'm a designer that has taught myself basic php/wordpress theming.*

This is a very specific question, I realize, but I'm hoping the experts can help me find some universal principle I've overlooked.

I am using the plugin posts 2 posts to generate a relationship between the CPT "speakers" to wordpress users (Relevant [plugin documentation](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Posts-2-Users))

I then want to show, on the single page for speakers, a link to all the blog posts by the related users. My problem is that get_author_posts_url returns a link to the correct related user, while get_the author gets some other, seemingly random user. All this within the same query!

This is my code:

```
$users = get_users( array(
    'connected_type' => 'authors_to_speakers',
    'connected_items' => $post,
) );
if($users){
foreach ( $users as $spost ){
    echo '<div class="related-tour-item"><a href="';
    echo get_author_posts_url($spost->ID);
    echo '">All posts by';
    echo get_the_author($spost->ID);
    echo '</a></div>';
```

}

The output is a correct link to the right author archive page and then another (different) user's name

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

[`get_the_author()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author) takes no arguments and must be used within the Loop (I guess it's the case).

```
/* get_the_author($spost->ID); Replace this. */
get_the_author(); // By this.
```

Comment: but $users is already returning users and not posts since I'm using get_users and not get_posts, right? so $spost should also be a user

Comment: You're right indeed. It's a bit confusing you called it $spost. Well, that means you're not running trough a custom Loop, the get_the_author() will return the author of the current page or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Sebastien's answer got me on the right track. I should not be using the_author, because I am not looking for the author of a post (My query is not returning a post, but a user), rather the name of the user.

I changed:

```
echo get_the_author($spost->ID);
```

to

```
 echo $spost->display_name;
```

Comment: I was about to tell you haha... Nice job